# addClass() function not being applied to an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
     <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <title>Working With DOM</title>
           <script src="jquery.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#gold").addClass("highlight");
        });

        </script>
       <style type="text/css">
        body{background-color:#FFCC66;}
        #wrap
       {margin:0 auto;
       border:2px solid #CC8320;
        height:500px;}

       h1{font-style:italic;
       color:#A48713; padding-left:10px;}


         #gold{width:200px;
        background-color:#D49F55;
         height:150px; margin:20px; float:left;height:200px}

        input{border:1px solid black; width:150px; margin:0 20px;           
       background-color:#AA9F55; color:#553F00;font-weight:bolder;text-align:center; }

      .info{border:1px solid black; width:150px;background-color:#AA9F55;        color:#553F00;font-weight:bolder;text-align:center;margin:0 20px; }
     .highlight{background-color:green;}
       </style>
    </head>

 <body>
     <div id="wrap">
     <h1> Learning Web Engineering Online</h1>



        <div  data-price="399.99" id="gold">
            <h3>Gold Member</h3>
           <ul class="course">
             <li>HTML5</li>
             <li>css3</li>
             <li>jquery</li>
          </ul>
     <form>
        <input type="button" value="GET PRICE"/>
      </form>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I am having problem with the code above that when using jquery i add class highlight to element with id=gold and inspect it in chrome, although the class is being added to the code the style rule mentioned in highlight class doesn't output in browser. the element is being selected but not styled. what am i doing wrong please help someone.

Comment: .highlight style is not applied because you are setting background-color with a more specific selector: #gold

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WYNpf/ it works

Comment: in the next time use "inspect element" of ur browser and have certain what do you need

Comment: @Jahnux73 it works because you are using !important statement

Comment: yes because of it. Is it a problem ? (if yes sorry, i'll remove my comment to don't disturb correct answer)

Comment: @Jahnux73 not a problem, its one way of doing it, but not the best as !important statement should be used in very last resort

Comment: @A.Wolff You teached me something ^^ thanks ( i'm autodidact no school )

Answer (score 1):

You should use `!important` to work it:

```
.highlight{background-color:green !important;}
```

#### Note:

Browser uses **ID** with higher importance than a **class name**.

Answer (score 1):

change your css to

```
#gold.highlight{background-color:green;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the priority style for `.highlight`. Just add `#gold` before the `.highlight` style

```
#gold.highlight{background-color:green;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is due to the precendence of CSS selectors. An `id` selector will override a `class` selector, so you need to either make the class selector more specific (preferred method):

```css
#gold.highlight { background-color: green; }
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z7CLj/)

Or aleternatively add `!important` to it:

```css
.highlight { background-color: green !important; }
```

However the latter can lead to issues when you have competing `!important` rules, so it's best to avoid it where possible.

Answer (score 0):

highlight gets applied but as there is background-color property defined in ID it will not be overridden by class value.

As mentioned by @cocco you can use #gold.highlight to override it.

Answer (score 0):

Id has greater precision due to conflict resolution, class css is overridden by your #gold id css

change your class

```
.highlight{background-color:green !important;}
```